# Cucumber and SpringBootTest via Failsafe plugin

Tags: maven, cucumber, integration-testing, maven-failsafe-plugin

I'm having issues getting my cucumber tests to be invoked. I'm using SpringBootTest for these and invoking them via the maven failsafe plugin. I know for a fact that the features path is correct because 1. If I run the tests directly using Intellij's runner, it runs all the tests and 2. If I run via Maven and use the wrong path Cucumber itself throws exceptions.

Please find relevant project excerpts below:

`CucumberIT.java`

```java
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {
                "src/test/resources/features/"
        },
        glue = {
                "classpath:com.company.pkg.integration.steps"
        }
)
public class CucumberIT {}
```

`CucumberContextLoader` to load the Spring Context for all features to access

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ConfigInitializer.class)
public class CucumberContextLoader {

    @Before // Note this is Cucumbers Before, not JUnits.
    public void setUp() {
    }
}
```

`pom.xml` Profile for running integration tests:

```xml
        <profile>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <properties>
                <skip.surefire.tests>true</skip.surefire.tests>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

The output that this all gives me is:

```
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M4:integration-test (default) @ my-rest-service ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
Mar 02, 2020 1:19:56 PM io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber <init>
WARNING: By default Cucumber is running in --non-strict mode.
This default will change to --strict and --non-strict will be removed.
You can use --strict or @CucumberOptions(strict = true) to suppress this warning
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  23.971 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-03-02T13:19:57-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Have you tried a non-milestone release of Failsafe?

Comment: `glue` doesn't need the `classpath` prefix btw. Just a package name.

Comment: @mpkorstanje same exact behavior on 2.22.2.

Comment: I don't see any problems with your setup. You'll have to start from scratch and make a proper MCVE.

Comment: @xandermonkey - have you find the soln ? i having the same error today also

Comment: @Arundev It's been a long time since I've done anything in this space as I switched jobs a while ago. Can't be of much help for more details here, apologies.